# Find CDF of $X$, where $X$ is the length of line

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

On a circumference of circle, whose center is $(0,0)$, a point T is being chosen and a tangent line is set through that point. Find CDF of random variable $X$ which represents the length of the line from the point T to the point where tangent line intersects with $O_x$ axis.

Let $O$ be $(0,0)$, also let A be the intersection point of tangent line with $O_x$(let's say we are in the first quadrant). The angle $\alpha$ - $\angle AOT $ can take values $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$. The solution 
 from my textbook is $X=|AT|=tan\alpha$, shouldn't it be $X=|AT|=tan\alpha |OA|$? That is my first question.

Now, when it comes to finding CDF it is always confusing to me how to find it when I don't have the PDF?

This is the solution $F_X(x)=P(tg\alpha < x)=P(\alpha < arctanx)=\frac{2}{\pi}arctanx$, when $x>0$. Why is it $\frac{2}{\pi}arctanx$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\triangle\mathrm{OTA}$ is a right triangle with hypotenuse $\rm\overline{OA}$, and right angle $\angle\rm OTA$.  You seek to find side length $\rm\lvert AT\rvert$ knowing the opposing angle $\angle\rm AOT $ (it is $\alpha$) and the radius of the circle $\lvert\rm OT\rvert$ (which is apparently one).

Recall that in kindergarten, tangent was defined as opposite over adjacent.  $\tan\angle\mathrm{AOT} =\dfrac{\lvert\mathrm{AT}\rvert}{\lvert\mathrm{OT}\rvert}$

$$\begin{align}X&=\lvert\mathrm{AT}\rvert\\&=\lvert\mathrm{OT}\rvert\tan\angle\mathrm{AOT}\\&=\tan\alpha\end{align}$$

Now $T$ is apparently selected without bias from points on the circle *in the first quadrant*, so $\alpha$ has a uniform distribution over $[0..\pi/2)$. Thus $\mathsf P(\alpha<y)=\tfrac{y}{\pi/2}\mathbf 1_{y\in[0..2\pi)}$ .

Thus by substitution:
$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X<x)&=\mathsf P(\tan\alpha <x)\\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(\alpha<\arctan x)\\[1ex]&=\mathbf 1_{x\in[0..\infty)}\cdot\tfrac{2}{\pi}\arctan x\end{align}$$